# Flutter firebase packages versions conflicting between messaging, core and analytics

Tags: firebase, flutter, version

I have 3 packages from firebase:
 `firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1`
`firebase_messaging:  ^7.0.3`
`firebase_analytics: ^7.0.1`
when I build it fails always cuz of versions.  I have tried changed versions to downgrade but couldn't able to build the app.

[image: consele error]

pod install --repo-update didn't work
all pods files remove and clear cache didn't work

Comment: Please add the result of the "flutter run --verbose" command as a text, not a screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you can't use firebase_analytics >=7.0.1 with older versions of core...

```
Because firebase_analytics >=7.0.1 depends on firebase_core ^0.7.0 and [app_name] depends on firebase_core ^0.5.0+1, firebase_analytics >=7.0.1 is forbidden.
```

Either update `firebase_core: ^0.7.0` or downgrade `firebase_analytics: ^6.0.2` and `firebase_messaging ^0.7.0`

Comment: I already did this downgrading but this time I got the same error with messaging package

Comment: Weird;
firebase_core@0.5.0+1, firebase_analytics@6.0.2, firebase_messaging@7.0.3 are compatible; Could you show what error are you getting? Maybe try `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`

Comment: firebase_messaging ^0.7.0 just compatible with this version firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1 with analytics 6.0.2 + cocoapods update worked